# Create-react-app: unhandled error event: Events.js.187

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, django-admin, yarnpkg

'm trying to create a new react app with yarn. after using the command create-react-app i keep getting an error unhandled events error. There's also a reference to django-admin.py in the error log for some reason and I can't make out the connection.Can i get some assistance. the log of the error is shown below

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\django-admin.py ENOENT
[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)[39m
[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\[4mcross-spawn[24m\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)[39m
[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)[39m {
  errno: [32m'ENOENT'[39m,
  code: [32m'ENOENT'[39m,
  syscall: [32m'spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\django-admin.py'[39m,
  path: [32m'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\django-admin.py'[39m,
  spawnargs: [
    [32m'/d'[39m,
    [32m'/s'[39m,
    [32m'/c'[39m,
    [32m'"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'[39m
  ]
}

C:\Users\HP\Documents\web dev\Angular 2>cd C:\Users\HP\Documents\web dev\Angular 2create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the following environment variables under PATH System Variables

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

Mine were missing for some reason but when I added them in this exact same problem vanished.